# Use regular expression to find all sequences of digits (of any length) in an input string

Tags: python, regex

Checking on my code and wonder what I am missing here that sometime it does not return 100% correct answer

```
# findDigitSequence(string) takes as input a string containing zero or more sequences 
# of digits and returns a list of all sequences in the string. The output list must 
# be sorted in the increasing order. You can use the 'sorted' function in python for 
# sorting the list. If no sequence is present, then the function should return 'None'. 

def findDigitSequence(string):
    
    digit = re.findall('[0-9]+',string)
    return digit

# Example Test Q1b
print( findDigitSequence("My number is 987654321 and my friend\'s number is 123456789.") )
# output ['123456789', '987654321']

print( findDigitSequence("Hello World!") )
# output None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sorting your output as instructed in the comments.  It may also be necessary to return 'None' as a string (depending on how the function is called)

```
return sorted(digit,key=int) or 'None'
```